# How to get all the assignee for a particular project using JIRA Rest api?

Tags: api, rest, jira, jira-rest-api

I am developing an iOS application and i have search functionality where in users can search for issues by selecting fields like project , version , assignee and i have all the rest api's for other functionalities except for assignee , i tried to find but i didn't get any Api. i was using the below Api - /rest/api/2/user/assignable/multiProjectSearch?username&projectKeys&startAt&maxResults

and it doesn't give me the exact results , can anybody point me in the right direction like how can i get assignee's for a particular project when i select a project in the search field.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that by assignees of the project you mean assigness from the issues that belong to the project. You can use search method:

```
https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#d2e4863
/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=PROJ_KEY&fields=assignee
```

Please take into account "startAt", "maxResults" parameters and returned "total" value that are used to support pagination. You may need to check the jira.search.view.default.max property in your JIRA: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CLOUDKB/Changing+maxResults+Parameter+for+JIRA+REST+API